# add data to sql database? Using odbc

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

High Im unsure how to add insert data to mysql using odbc?

I have a table called User and I would like to add generic details to it, Name, location etc etc

```
  {
      string = textbox1.text("Name");

      OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite; User=root; Password=;");
      cn.Open();
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO User (Name)");

      cmd.Parameters.Insert(Name into @name);

    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking but I see a few problems with your code:

```
  string tbValue = textbox1.text("Name"); //added variable name

  OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite; User=root; Password=;");
  cn.Open();
  OdbcCommand cmd = 
        new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO User (Name) VALUES (?)"); // fixed incomplete insert statement.

  cmd.Parameters.Add(tbValue); //add the parameter to the command
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //actually run the sql
```

There may be other problems but give this a try for starters and let us know if you have any specific problems.

Comment: Well, that was what I was in the middle of typing, and you beat me to it Abe!!  Rep points for you.

Comment: sorry the values would be the stored string from the textbox. Not sure if it would just be insert into user (name) values (tbvalue)